# THREE js camera.postion.set avoid direct display

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera

I have a button that create a canvas THREE js on click. When I set a position to my camera, my mesh is not displayed directly but I need to click once on the canvas to display it. Do you know how to correct this ?

```
         function FirstCut() {

var scene, camera, renderer, controls;

//stl loader from https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html
// cf example https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSG.html

//with obj

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xeeeeee);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 800 / 500, 1, 2000);

    //camera.position.set(50, 500, 0);
    camera.position.x = 50;
    camera.position.y = 500;
    camera.position.z = 0;

    var axeX = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    camera.rotateOnAxis(axeX, -1);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 500, 0));

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
    //les valeurs de min and max distance sont choisies pour que le filet ne disparaisse pas quand on le fait tourner
    controls.minDistance = 0;
    controls.maxDistance = 1000;
    //scene

    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x101030);
    scene.add(ambient);
    //scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(1000, 20));
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 0);
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    var widthH = parseInt(document.getElementById("wdthH").value) || 0; // H for Head
    var widthT = parseInt(document.getElementById("wdthT").value) || 0; // T for tail
    var height = parseInt(document.getElementById("hght").value) || 0;  // flank


    //création du pavé
    var EmportePieceH = new THREE.BoxGeometry(300, 60, widthH);
    var EmportePieceT = new THREE.BoxGeometry(300, 60, widthT);
    var EmportePieceB = new THREE.BoxGeometry(height, 60, 520);

    var paveMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ wireframe: true });

    // création du meshage et material
    var EmportePieceMeshH = new THREE.Mesh(EmportePieceH, paveMaterial);
    var EmportePieceMeshT = new THREE.Mesh(EmportePieceT, paveMaterial);
    var paveMeshB = new THREE.Mesh(EmportePieceB, paveMaterial);

    var zH = 247 - widthH / 2;
    var zT = -247 + widthT / 2;
    EmportePieceMeshH.position.set(0, 30, zH);
    EmportePieceMeshT.position.set(0, 30, zT);
    paveMeshB.position.set(-95 + height / 2, 30, 0);
    var EmportePieceBSPH = new ThreeBSP(EmportePieceMeshH);
    var EmportePieceBSPT = new ThreeBSP(EmportePieceMeshT);
    var paveBSPB = new ThreeBSP(paveMeshB);

    //scene.add(EmportePieceMeshH);
    //scene.add(EmportePieceMeshT);
    //scene.add(paveMeshB);


    // texture
    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.onProgress = function (item, loaded, total) {
        console.log(item, loaded, total);
    };
    var texture = new THREE.Texture();
    var onProgress = function (xhr) {
        if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
            console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
        }
    };
    var onError = function (xhr) {
    };

    var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);
    loader.load('/Scan/filet_1kg500-reposition-reduit_material_0.jpg', function (image) {
        texture.image = image;
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
    });

    var width = parseInt(document.getElementById("wdth").value) || 0;

    //création du pavé
    var paveGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(250, 250, width);
    var paveMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ wireframe: true });

    // création du meshage parallélépipède avec material
    var paveMesh = new THREE.Mesh(paveGeom, paveMaterial);

    var z0 = -247 + widthH;
    paveMesh.position.set(0, 0, z0);

    var paveBSP = new ThreeBSP(paveMesh);
    //scene.add(paveMesh);

    //tableau des volumes
    var tabVolumes = new Array();

    // model
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
    loader.load('/Scan/filet_1kg500-reposition-reduit.obj', function (object) {
        object.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                child.material.map = texture;

                var geo = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(child.geometry);
                var filetMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true });
                var filetMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, filetMaterial);
                //scene.add(filetMesh);
                var newBSPH, newBSPT, newBSPB, newBSP2, newBSP1, filletBSP
                var filetBSP = new ThreeBSP(filetMesh);

                    newBSPH = filetBSP.intersect(EmportePieceBSPH);
                    newBSPT = filetBSP.intersect(EmportePieceBSPT);
                    newBSPB = filetBSP.intersect(paveBSPB);
                    newBSP2 = filetBSP.subtract(EmportePieceBSPH);
                    newBSP1 = newBSP2.subtract(paveBSPB);
                    filletBSP = newBSP1.subtract(EmportePieceBSPT);

                ////////////////////subtract//////////////////////////////

                var newFilet = new THREE.Geometry();
                newFilet = filletBSP.toGeometry();
                var newFilletMesh = new THREE.Mesh(newFilet, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture }));
                newFilletMesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);

                ///////////////////////////////////création morceaux découpés///////////////////////////////////////////

                var HeadFillet = new THREE.Geometry();
                var TailFillet = new THREE.Geometry();
                var degraissageFillet = new THREE.Geometry();
                HeadFillet = newBSPH.toGeometry();
                TailFillet = newBSPT.toGeometry();
                degraissageFillet = newBSPB.toGeometry();


                /////////////////////////////////calcul des volumes des 1ers morceaux/////////////////////////////////////////

                if (widthH != 0) {
                    tabVolumes[0] = calculateVolume2(HeadFillet);
                } else { tabVolumes[0] = 0;}

                if (widthT != 0) {
                //alert(tabVolumes[0]);
                    tabVolumes[1] = calculateVolume2(TailFillet); 
                } else { tabVolumes[1] = 0; }

                if (height != 0) {
                    tabVolumes[2] = calculateVolume2(degraissageFillet);
                } else { tabVolumes[2] = 0; }

                var ind = 3;

                var HeadFilletMesh = new THREE.Mesh(HeadFillet, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture }));
                var TailFilletMesh = new THREE.Mesh(TailFillet, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture }));
                var degraissageFilletMesh = new THREE.Mesh(degraissageFillet, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture }));



                HeadFilletMesh.position.set(0, 0, 20);
                degraissageFilletMesh.position.set(-20, 0, 0);
                TailFilletMesh.position.set(0, 0, -20);
                scene.add(HeadFilletMesh);
                scene.add(TailFilletMesh);
                scene.add(degraissageFilletMesh);

                //scene.add(newFilletMesh);
                var cloneHeadFilletMesh = HeadFilletMesh.clone();
                var cloneTailFilletMesh = TailFilletMesh.clone();
                var clonedegraissageFilletMesh = degraissageFilletMesh.clone();

                var mesh_decoupe = new THREE.Object3D;
                mesh_decoupe.add(cloneHeadFilletMesh);
                mesh_decoupe.add(cloneTailFilletMesh);
                mesh_decoupe.add(clonedegraissageFilletMesh);

                if (width != 0) {
                var paveGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(300, 300, width);
                var paveMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ wireframe: true });


                var fillet2BSP = new ThreeBSP(newFilletMesh);

                var intersectionPave = new THREE.Geometry();
                intersectionPave = fillet2BSP.intersect(paveBSP);

                var geometryPave = new THREE.Geometry();
                geometryPave = intersectionPave.toGeometry();
                var newMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometryPave, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture }));


                //alert(geometryPave.faces.length);

                while (geometryPave.faces.length != 0) {


                    var z = paveMesh.position.z + width + 5;

                    paveMesh.position.set(0, 0, z);
                    paveBSP = new ThreeBSP(paveMesh);
                    //scene.add(paveMesh);

                    fillet2BSP = new ThreeBSP(newFilletMesh);

                    intersectionPave = filletBSP.intersect(paveBSP);
                    geometryPave = intersectionPave.toGeometry();

                    tabVolumes[ind] = calculateVolume2(geometryPave);
                    ind = ind + 1;

                    var newMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometryPave, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture }));
                    newMesh.position.set(0, 0, newMesh.position.z);
                    scene.add(newMesh);

                    var meshSave = newMesh.clone();
                    mesh_decoupe.add(meshSave);
                   }



                } else {
                    scene.add(newFilletMesh);



                    tabVolumes[3] = 0;
                    tabVolumes[4] = calculateVolume2(newFilet);
                }



                    //    }
                    //}
                    //else {
                    //    scene.add(newFilletMesh);

                    //    tabVolumes[ind] = calculateVolume2(newFilet);
                    //}


                    //alert(calculateVolume2(newBSP.toGeometry()));

                    //afficher les volumes dans la textarea


                    var txtVolume = document.getElementById("txtVolume");
                    txtVolume.value = tabVolumes.join("\n");

                    //var exporter = new THREE.OBJExporter();
                    //var result = exporter.parse(mesh_decoupe);
                    //var blob = new Blob([result], { type: 'text/plain' });
                    //saveAs(blob, 'dechets.obj');

                }
           });
            //scene.add(object);

        }, onProgress, onError);


        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(800, 500, false);

        document.getElementById('canvas3D').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('canvas3D').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    }

    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);


    }




    function volumeOfT(p1, p2, p3) {
        var v321 = p3.x * p2.y * p1.z;
        var v231 = p2.x * p3.y * p1.z;
        var v312 = p3.x * p1.y * p2.z;
        var v132 = p1.x * p3.y * p2.z;
        var v213 = p2.x * p1.y * p3.z;
        var v123 = p1.x * p2.y * p3.z;
        return (-v321 + v231 + v312 - v132 - v213 + v123) / 6.0;
    }

    function calculateVolume2(object) {
        var volumes = 0.0;

        for (var i = 0; i < object.faces.length; i++) {
            var Pi = object.faces[i].a;
            var Qi = object.faces[i].b;
            var Ri = object.faces[i].c;
            //alert (Pi);

            var P = new THREE.Vector3(object.vertices[Pi].x, object.vertices[Pi].y, object.vertices[Pi].z);
            //alert(object.vertices[Pi].x);
            var Q = new THREE.Vector3(object.vertices[Qi].x, object.vertices[Qi].y, object.vertices[Qi].z);
            var R = new THREE.Vector3(object.vertices[Ri].x, object.vertices[Ri].y, object.vertices[Ri].z);
            volumes += volumeOfT(P, Q, R);
        }

        return Math.abs(volumes);

    }
}
```

HTML :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/three.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/ThreeCSG.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/STLLoader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/OBJLoader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/FirstCut.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/OBJExporter.js"></script>

<script> init();</script>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
        <br />

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="../images/schema_decoupe.png" alt="saumon1" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4-right">
                <div class="menuRight">
                    <h5>
                        Gabarit selected: @ViewBag.gabarits
                        <br />
                        Packaging selected: @ViewBag.packs
                        <br />
                        With or without bones: @ViewBag.bones
                        <br />
                        Skin selected: @ViewBag.skins
                        <br />
                        Trim Selected: @ViewBag.trims
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="inputRow clear" id="dimensionsNotRound" data-role="tooltip">

            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h3>1. Width of head cut: <input id="wdthH" class="numeric-textbox" type="number" value=""> </h3>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4-right">
                    <h3>2. Width of tail cut: <input id="wdthT" class="numeric-textbox" type="number" value=""> </h3>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h3>3. Height of lower cut: <input id="hght" class="numeric-textbox" type="number" value=""></h3>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4-right">
                    <h3>Width of one fillet: <input id="wdth" class="numeric-textbox" type="number" value=""></h3>
                </div>

            </div>

            <br />
            <br />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" style="float:left; z-index:1000;"> @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home") <i class="icon icon-caret-right"></i></button>*@

            <br />
            <h3>Volume of the cuts (head, tail, skimming, filets):</h3><textarea id="txtVolume" name="txtVolume"></textarea>

            <button id="download" type="button">Download</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you auto render your scene?

Comment: Do you mean autoClear ?

Comment: No, some code like this `render();
function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}`, It seems you only render the scene in your click event handler. Or can you supply complete code?

Comment: Yes I did this already `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(800, 500, false);

            document.getElementById('canvas3D').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('canvas3D').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
 

        }` When I delete the lines positioning the camera, everything is ok..

Comment: Your code seems ok, except `var axeX = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    camera.rotateOnAxis(axeX, -1);` wouldn't affect anything, because `camera.lookAt` would set camera orientation. show more complete code would help.

Comment: I edited the post with complete code. I was wondering if I use the mouse to orientate the camera maybe this will activate the renderer ?

Comment: Yes, Maybe, render initialized when you click, try to make the init() and animate() function auto execute when the document loaded.

Comment: Problem is the 2 functions are depending on input field defined on the same page...

Comment: In the `init` function, you just initialize scene, render, camera, light, controls, and in your click handler function, you do loading job, get input from dom element, load the obj model, and add it to the scene. once document loaded call `init()` and `animate()`.

Comment: Just define them outside, set value in the 'init' function, then you can use them in other functions. I need to go to bed, leave a message to let me know if you solve the problem or have some other problems, I will check it tomorrow. Finally, good luck!

Comment: Hello, I tried your trick but unfortunately I still have the same issue.. I used `<body onload="init()">` and then using the button for the `loading()` function.

Comment: Could you show your complete code both js and html?

Comment: Here it is, thanks for your help !

Comment: I edited the post*

Comment: ok, I'm working on it.

Comment: I tried your code, I used a simpler obj loading function, the model displayed without clicking on canvas, but I got an error `Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': Tainted canvases may not be loaded`, I don't know what it means. I separated your init function into two functions, OnButtonClick() and init(), initialize scene render and so on in init(), handle click event and loading model. here is a jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/craigli/8vmk9305/).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it this evening !

Comment: Hello Craig.Li could you just tell me what did you modify in HTML page, when and how do you call init() animate() ?

Comment: I didn't modify HTML file, I add an event listener `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", FirstCut, false);`. when document loaded, call FirstCut(), init() and animate() would be executed.